¿Cómo reemplazar parte de una columna en MySQL usando expresiones regulares sin afectar el resto del contenido de esa columna?
Yo tengo en una tabla llamada posts una columna llamada post_content con valores como estos:
[dvref libro="48|5|1|12|1015"]
[dvref libro="48|5|33|37|1018"]
[dvref libro="48|10|7|13|1016"]                                                     
[dvref libro="40|9|51|62|1126"]                                                     
[dvref libro="48|6|19|23|1067"]

Y necesito reemplazar ese contenido por lo siguiente:
[commentarii id="1015"]
[commentarii id="1018"]
[commentarii id="1016"]
[commentarii id="1126"]
[commentarii id="1067"]

Es decir,

Cambiar dvref libro por commentarii id
De los valores entre comillas, obtener solamente el valor que está después del último |, limpio, sin ese separador.

Sé que lo podría hacer con REGEXP_REPLACE() pero no encuentro la expresión adecuada para hacer este UPDATE.
Otra cosa muy importante es que algunas columnas pueden tener otro contenido aparte de [dvref .... ] y que ese contenido debe quedar intacto en la actualización.
¿Cuál sería la expresión regular para hacer este cambio?

Porque una regexp y no directamente un substring desde el ultimo | y apendar el texto que queres??? lo otro no se puede arreglar con substring de alguna forma?

De paso podrias agregar un ejemplo del resto de la cadena? no vaya a ser que alguien consiga la regexp pero rompa el resto tambien...

@gbianchi lo de hacerlo con REGEXP es suposición mía. Si hay otras formas, bienvenidas serán (esa es una de las grandes ventajas de preguntar a quienes dominan mejor el tema). En cuanto al resto del contenido puede ser cualquier cosa. Se trata de posts con contenido HTML por lo general,.así como etiquetas tipo shortcode (WordPress) parecidas a las ya mostradas en la pregunta. O sea, no hay un patrón único con respecto al resto de contenido, el cual quiero conservar intacto.

Ese detalle es importante: ¿buscás hacer los reemplazos solo vía consultas SQL o a nivel de aplicación? Teniendo en cuenta que las expresiones regulares no siempre son la solución a todo...

Tengo un fiddle que resuelve tu problema, pero siempre y cuando esa cadena este siempre al principio... podes agregar ejemplos de cadenas (aunque no esten completas) para poder probarlos con otras cadenas???

@padaleiana se trata de una normalización. No me importa hacerlo a nivel de SQL o vía aplicación. Para mí lo más práctico sería escribir una consulta que me normalice esos datos, los cuales fueron creados en diversas etapas del desarrollo y usando técnicas diversas, por esos los datos a veces tienen sólo el patrón [dvref libro ...] y a veces tienen más cosas, entre otras, algunos empiezan por [dvref otraCosa ...], otros empiezan por contenido HTML cualquiera, otros tienen saltos de línea, o tabulaciones, o comentarios HTML, o por shortcode cualquiera [cualquier shortcode ...].

@gbianchi el problema es que no hay un patrón, puede haber lo que sea antes y después de [dvref libro ...] o puede no haber nada o puede haber un espacio en blanco, etc. Estoy tratando de normalizar contenido que se escribió hace años, casi siempre usando el editor visual de Wordpress, el cual además ha cambiado con el tiempo. Por eso, mucho de ese contenido ahora empieza con comentarios de bloques y cosas así. La idea es normalizar a sólo el estilo de shortcode tipo [commentarii id="..."] pero guardando otro contenido HTML escrito a mano, el cual aún no está normalizado en la BD.

Ok.. se puede hacer contando caracteres y buscando solo eso para reemplazar.. dejame probar algo mas, y vamos a llegar a una query que te devuelve lo que queres... igual, tambien se podria guardar la cadena a reemplazar en otro lado y luego volverla a meter, pero vos veras que te conviene mas...

¿El contenido de libro a modificar siempre es de 5 números separados por |? Suena mejor aprovechar las expresiones regulares en PHP -que son mas poderosas-, no obstante, aún puedes utilizar una expresión en la consulta como WHERE post_content regexp '[dvref libro="[0-9|]+"'.

Las expresiones regulares de mySQL son algo extrañas, como suele ser todo con el motor.
A mi, me da el resultado esta:
select   id
       , post_content 
       , REGEXP_REPLACE(post_content, '\\[dvref libro=\\"([0-9]+\\|){4}', '[comentarii id="') 
  from posts;

Que la he construido a partir de la expresión regular normal:
\[dvref libro=\"(?:[0-9]+\|){4}

que puedes probar y encontrar una explicación a su estructura en cualquier sitio de expresiones regulares online, como regex101.com
En el manual de mySQL, que has enlazado en la pregunta, puedes ver que mySQL requiere doble barra invertida \\ como secuencia de escape para cualquier caracter especial que sea literal en la expresión regular, como el corchete [ y la barra vertical |, en tu caso.
Lo que hace esta sustitución, al final, es, para cada coincidencia, reemplaza con el texto dado. De esta forma, y basándome en que en los datos de entrada siempre hay 5 grupos de números y te quieres quedar con el último, he hecho que la coincidencia termine en el cuarto grupo de dígitos (incluyendo la barra vertical).
El update, al final, sería algo como:
update posts
   set post_content = REGEXP_REPLACE(post_content, '\\[dvref libro=\\"([0-9]+\\|){4}', '[comentarii id="')
 where post_content like '%dvref libro=%';

El where, en realidad, es opcional, pero si tienes un gran volumen de datos, o triggers asociados, te ayuda a que se toquen solo las filas que contienen la cadena.
Hice una prueba en dbfiddle, con este script:
CREATE TABLE posts (
    id int not null auto_increment primary key
  , post_content VARCHAR(300)
);

insert into posts (post_content) values 
  ('Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet [dvref libro="48|5|1|12|1015"] consectetur adipiscing elit')
, ('sed do eiusmod tempor')
, ('incididunt ut [dvref libro="48|5|33|37|1018"] labore et dolore [dvref libro="48|10|7|13|1016"]')
, ('magna aliqua.')
, ('[dvref libro="40|9|51|62|1126"]')
, ('[dvref libro="48|6|19|23|1067"]')
, ('Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris')
;

Después de hacer el update, un select sobre la tabla devuelve:



id
post_content




1
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet [comentarii id="1015"] consectetur adipiscing elit


2
sed do eiusmod tempor


3
incididunt ut [comentarii id="1018"] labore et dolore [comentarii id="1016"]


4
magna aliqua.


5
[comentarii id="1126"]


6
[comentarii id="1067"]


7
Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris



Como puedes ver, las filas que no tienen coincidencias, las deja tal cual.
Finalmente, decir que es un gran gusto escribir esta respuesta para una de las personas que más contribuye en el sitio. Espero te sea útil.

Tu respuesta ha funcionado exactamente como esperaba. ¡Muchísimas gracias!

Es un tremendo gusto, @A.Cedano. Un saludo!

Esperando no abusar de tu gentileza. Tengo este otro caso. Cambiar este patrón [celref id="716|9|10|15|0|0"] por este: [celref id="716"]. Se trataría de desechar todos los valores, excepto el primero. Además, ya hay posts que tienen el nuevo patrón y supongo habría que evitarlos en el UPDATE. ¿Si no es mucha molestia, me echas una mano con la REGEX? Yo me ocupo de escribir la consulta.

@A.Cedano es un caso distinto, y lo que veo complicado es que ahora te quieres quedar con un dato que no está al final, lo que sería fácil de resolver si hubiera sustitución por grupos, pero hasta dónde ví, el motor no la soporta. Déjame hacer algunas pruebas y vemos si la sección de comentarios nos da para resolverlo. Te comento luego.

@A.Cedano, si lo soporta. Creo que es mejor que veas el fiddle. Mira si está bien la cadena, espero que si, y la sustitución. En este caso, la explicación es un poco más amplia, pues estamos utilizando un grupo de captura, pero el resultado diría que es el que esperas.

Gracias nuevamente. En MySQL 8 funciona, pero la base de datos está en MariaDB versión 10.6 y no recupera el primer elemento del grupo, sino que cambia el dato por  $1. Ver fiddle.

Usando SUBSTRING_INDEX he podido adaptarlo para que funcione con mi versión actual de MariaDB. Quedaría así: CONCAT('[celref id=',SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(post_content, '[celref id=', -1), '|', 1),'"]')).  Ver fiddle. Muchas gracias, sobre todo por ayudarme a encontrar estas dos REGEX que me han facilitado enormemente el trabajo.

O bien este usando TRIM y LEADING
, sintácticamente más simple: CONCAT(TRIM(LEADING 'celref id=\"' FROM SUBSTRING_INDEX(post_content, '|', 1)),'"]'). Ver fiddle.

@A.Cedano hay una etiqueta [tag:mariadb] que hubiese venido bien en la pregunta para hacer allí las pruebas. Generalizando, en preguntas de mysql, también vendría bien la versión, pues hay muchas diferencias (mejoras) en la 8 y superiores.

Ahora que ví los fiddles, me dí cuenta que si la expresión aparece 2 veces en la cadena, la sustitución la hace siempre por el ID del primero (mira la fila 3).  Si tu base de datos tiene casos como ese, no te serviría la solución. Si ese es el caso, creo que probablemente ameritaría una nueva pregunta y vemos de buscarle la solución ya sabiendo el motor. Si no lo es, que suerte!.

Usando un poco de juego de cadenas, y varios subquerys (pero esto para que se entienda, seguro se puede optimizar mucho mas) se puede llegar a una expresión que reemplace la cadena que vos querés, por la cadena nueva construida en base al contenido de la cadena actual.
Para ello, utilice lo siguiente:
CREATE TABLE Product (
  Name VARCHAR(100)
);

INSERT INTO Product(Name) VALUES ('[dvref libro="48|5|1|12|1015"] [dvreg libro="48|5|1|12|1022"]');
INSERT INTO Product(Name) VALUES ('[dvreg libro="48|5|1|12|1022"] [dvref libro="48|5|33|37|1018"]');
INSERT INTO Product(Name) VALUES ('[dvreg libro="48|5|1|12|1022"] [dvref libro="48|10|7|13|1016"] [dvreg libro="48|5|1|12|1022"]');

Utilice lo que vos querías poniendo al principio, al medio y al final.
Fijate la sutil diferencia entre las cadenas, la que queremos reemplazar es siempre dvref.. la otra, a propósito, la llame dvreg pero mantuve absolutamente todo igual
Select name,
    locate(']',name,locate('[dvref libro="',Name)+LENGTH('[dvref libro="')) as fin,
  locate('[dvref libro="',Name) as principiocadena,
    SUBSTRING_INDEX(
      SUBSTRING_INDEX(
        mid(name,
        locate('[dvref libro="',Name),
        locate(']',name,locate('[dvref libro="',Name))-locate('[dvref libro="',Name)+1
       )
                      , '|', -1)
      ,'"',1) as numaponer,
      mid(name,
        locate('[dvref libro="',Name),
        locate(']',name,locate('[dvref libro="',Name))-locate('[dvref libro="',Name)+1
       ) as cadenaacambiar,
       SUBSTRING_INDEX(
        mid(name,
        locate('[dvref libro="',Name),
        locate(']',name,locate('[dvref libro="',Name))-locate('[dvref libro="',Name)+1
       )
                      , '|', -1) as elnumero

from product;

Este query nos devuelve lo siguiente:



name
fin
principiocadena
numaponer
cadenaacambiar
elnumero




[dvref libro="48|5|1|12|1015"][dvreg libro="48|5|1|12|1022"]
30
1
1015
[dvref libro="48|5|1|12|1015"]
1015"]


[dvreg libro="48|5|1|12|1022"] [dvref libro="48|5|33|37|1018"]
62
32
1018
[dvref libro="48|5|33|37|1018"]
1018"]


[dvreg libro="48|5|1|12|1022"] [dvref libro="48|10|7|13|1016"] [dvreg libro="48|5|1|12|1022"]
62
32
1016
[dvref libro="48|10|7|13|1016"]
1016"]



Donde observamos que tenemos el campo, y varios valores que nos sirven para identificar la cadena que queremos reemplazar dentro del string, inclusive el "numero" que queremos poner (como numero y como cadena con los caracteres extra.
para ello utilizamos las funciones mid, substring_index y locate para ubicar las partes de la cadena.
una vez que tenemos esto, jugamos un poco mas con los resultado para seguir avanzando...
select 
p.name,
p.fin,
p.principiocadena,
mid(p.name,p.principiocadena,
        p.fin-p.principiocadena+1
       ) as sinresto,

  concat(
           '[commentarii id="',
p.elnumero
          ) as cadena2
from 
(
Select name,
    locate(']',name,locate('[dvref libro="',Name)+LENGTH('[dvref libro="')) as fin,
  locate('[dvref libro="',Name) as principiocadena,
    SUBSTRING_INDEX(
      SUBSTRING_INDEX(
        mid(name,
        locate('[dvref libro="',Name),
        locate(']',name,locate('[dvref libro="',Name))-locate('[dvref libro="',Name)+1
       )
                      , '|', -1)
      ,'"',1) as numaponer,
  SUBSTRING_INDEX(
        mid(name,
        locate('[dvref libro="',Name),
        locate(']',name,locate('[dvref libro="',Name))-locate('[dvref libro="',Name)+1
       )
                      , '|', -1) as elnumero

from product) as p;

con el siguiente resultado:



name
fin
principiocadena
sinresto
cadena2




[dvref libro="48|5|1|12|1015"] [dvreg libro="48|5|1|12|1022"]
30
1
[dvref libro="48|5|1|12|1015"]
[commentarii id="1015"]


[dvreg libro="48|5|1|12|1022"] [dvref libro="48|5|33|37|1018"]
62
32
[dvref libro="48|5|33|37|1018"]
[commentarii id="1018"]


[dvreg libro="48|5|1|12|1022"] [dvref libro="48|10|7|13|1016"] [dvreg libro="48|5|1|12|1022"]
62
32
[dvref libro="48|10|7|13|1016"]
[commentarii id="1016"]



Para luego, seguir jugando un poco mas y llegar a esto:
select q.name,
q.cadena2,
replace(q.name,q.sinresto,q.cadena2) as final2
from (
select 
p.name,
p.fin,
p.principiocadena,
mid(p.name,p.principiocadena,
        p.fin-p.principiocadena+1
       ) as sinresto,
p.numaponer,
  concat(
           '[commentarii id="',
p.elnumero
          ) as cadena2
from 
(
Select name,
    locate(']',name,locate('[dvref libro="',Name)+LENGTH('[dvref libro="')) as fin,
  locate('[dvref libro="',Name) as principiocadena,
    SUBSTRING_INDEX(
      SUBSTRING_INDEX(
        mid(name,
        locate('[dvref libro="',Name),
        locate(']',name,locate('[dvref libro="',Name))-locate('[dvref libro="',Name)+1
       )
                      , '|', -1)
      ,'"',1) as numaponer,
  SUBSTRING_INDEX(
        mid(name,
        locate('[dvref libro="',Name),
        locate(']',name,locate('[dvref libro="',Name))-locate('[dvref libro="',Name)+1
       )
                      , '|', -1) as elnumero

from product) as p) as q;




name
cadena2
final2




[dvref libro="48|5|1|12|1015"] [dvreg libro="48|5|1|12|1022"]
[commentarii id="1015"]
[commentarii id="1015"] [dvreg libro="48|5|1|12|1022"]


[dvreg libro="48|5|1|12|1022"] [dvref libro="48|5|33|37|1018"]
[commentarii id="1018"]
[dvreg libro="48|5|1|12|1022"][commentarii id="1018"]


[dvreg libro="48|5|1|12|1022"] [dvref libro="48|10|7|13|1016"] [dvreg libro="48|5|1|12|1022"]
[commentarii id="1016"]
[dvreg libro="48|5|1|12|1022"] [commentarii id="1016"] [dvreg libro="48|5|1|12|1022"]



